# If condition for 0 and blank in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I would like below condition.

if key = 0 then below should work.

```
$key = 0;
if($key){
  //code should execute
}
```

But if the key is blank then it should not work.

```
$key ="";
if($key){
  //code should not execute
}
```

Comment: @DavidJohn It should, `empty($key)` returns true, if `$key = 0`. http://www.deformedweb.co.uk/php_variable_tests.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work will strings / ints, but you will see a warning if you try to use this code when `$key` is an array.

```
if(strlen($key) > 0) {
  // execute
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply do this:

```
if($key === 0) {
    // add your code
}
```